# IsolatedStorageFileStream throwing "IsolatedStorageExeption was unhandled"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, text-files, xna-4.0, isolatedstorage

Basically I'm writing code that creates a new file in the IsolatedStorage, I'm sure that I'm closing the streams correctly but there must be something that's missing, could you have a look at it to make sure I'm not missing something obvious?

Here's my save function, it's where the error is thrown and is called at the end of a game once the user enters his/her name:

```
public void SaveHighScores(string NewName, int NewScore)
{
    SortHighScores(NewName, NewScore);

    IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    try
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("HighScores.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(MyScores[i].Name);
                    writer.WriteLine(MyScores[i].Score);
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
            isoStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (IsolatedStorageException e)
    {
        throw e; // "IsolatedStorageException was unhandled" error now occurs here
    }
}
```

And here is my Read Function, it is called once at the beginning of the game during initialisation:

```
public void ReadHighScores()
{
    IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    if (isoStore.FileExists("HighScores.txt"))
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("HighScores.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        MyScores[i].Name = reader.ReadLine();
                        string scoreString = reader.ReadLine();
                        MyScores[i].Score = Convert.ToInt32(scoreString);
                        i++;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                isoStream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!failedRead)
        {
            failedRead = true;
            ReadHighScores();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

[EDIT]

Ok so for some reason this now works the first time I call the save game function on a fresh install of the app, however the next time I play or when I restart the game and play again it crashes when it tries to save, which is odd, is `FileMode.CreateNew` probably where I'm going wrong?

[EDIT]

Yup, `FileMode.CreateNew` throws an exeption when a file already exists so I added `isoStore.DeleteFile("HighScores.txt")` before I create the new file, now works like a dream :)

[SOLVED]

Comment: Have you tried putting Try Catch Around it? Is it throwing the error during runtime or as you compile?

Comment: Runtime, and I'll try adding a try catch as soon as I'm done eating my dinner

Comment: Just updated my post, error now occurs when I'm throwing the exception

Answer (score 1):

`FileMode.CreateNew` throws an exception when the file already exists, so you have to call `isoStore.DeleteFile(string FileName)` before creating the new file or alternatively if you don't absolutely need to use `FileMode.CreateNew` use `FileMode.Create` instead

Comment: Use FileMode.Create instead.